# ImportError while importing ToneAnalayzer from ibm_watson

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, importerror, ibm-watson

while I tried to import ToneAnalyzerV3 from ibm_watson using the code :

```
from ibm_watson import ToneAnalyzerV3
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator
```

but its showing:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'ToneAnalyzerV3' from 'ibm_watson'
> (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ibm_watson/**init**.py)

while I was installing ibm_watson library there was also another error

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
google-colab 1.0.0 requires requests\~=2.23.0, but you have requests 2.27.1 which is incompatible.
datascience 0.10.6 requires folium==0.2.1, but you have folium 0.8.3 which is incompatible
```

but when I rerun the cell containing the code

```
!pip install ibm_watson
```

it was gone

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have conflicting requirements across different projects.

To avoid conflicts like this leaking across projects, I would recommend isolating each environment using virtualenv or equivalent.